# Making a registry entry post installation

Tags: wix

While I was searching for the answers I found that the registry entries are made during installation only. In my installer once the installation is done then there comes a dialogue box which contains one checkbox. Based upon the checkbox value I want to make the registry entry.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why does the checkbox item need to occur after installation execution sequence is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All system modifications (such as file installation or registry modifications) should occur DURING installation. There is a REASON for that - to make installation transactional (all or nothing), and to allow clean uninstall and repair.

Suggestion: if you want to put some user setting (a-la 'user agreed to receive marketing emails'), better do it yourself (as a custom action for example). Or better yet, in your own program (do not put it in the MSI installer)

A custom action in principle can be run in any execution sequence (including UI sequence), so you will be able to run it any time (i.e. even after that dialog)

Another option is to collect data (checkbox value) BEFORE install. Then you can include it as part of normal install sequence (as registry element)

Comment: Thanks. I have done it by taking the input before installation.

Comment: Could you pls share one custom action example ?

Comment: @Pranavka do a Google search on `WiX Installer Custom Action".. Lots of examples are available.